# Javascript - sum and delete same values

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays

I Want to sum all price values of an array for duplicated elements in array... I have this array:

```js
var products = [["product_1", 6, "hamburger"],["product_2", 10, "cola"],["product_2", 7, "cola"], ["product1", 4, "hamburger"]]
```

And this is what I want:

```js
var products = [["product_1", 10, "hamburger"],["product_2", 17, "cola"]]
```

Can any good soul help me?

Comment: What is `product_1`? A string?

Comment: Yes, I forgot  to show it, srry

Comment: did you try anything so far?

Comment: I would suggest using an Array#reduce iterator. It's perfect for this kind of thing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write `........, ["product_1", 4, "hamburger"]]`.

You can use `Object.values()` and `Array#reduce` methods as in the following demo:

```js
const 
  products = [
    ["product_1", 6, "hamburger"],
    ["product_2", 10, "cola"],
    ["product_2", 7, "cola"],
    ["product_1", 4, "hamburger"]
  ],

  output = Object.values(
    products.reduce(
      (acc, [id, num, name]) =>
      ({ ...acc,
        [id]: [id, (acc[id] && acc[id][1] || 0) + num, name]
      }), {}
    )
  );

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Pretty gnarly considering all the advanced syntax and `reduce` being combined. Some comments would really help readers understand what's happening.